# Exclude signature from attachment look up macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm working on a macro which checks the attachment name against the subject name and the domain.

At the moment there's a couple of minor issues, I don't want the macro to recognise images in the signature as an attachment. Solutions I've seen include using an if statement to work out the size, so for example only check attachments over 5kb etc.

The other issue is, if there is no attachment at all, the macro falls over! I think I need another if statement in there at the end to do an item count but I'm not sure how that alters my conditions at the end of the macro!

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim outRecips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim outRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim outPropAcc As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    Dim strDomain As String
    Dim lngPreDom As Long
    Dim lngPostDom As Long
    Dim strSubject As String

    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim strAttachment As String

    Dim Response As String
'   set domain value

    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    Set outRecips = Item.Recipients

    For Each outRecip In outRecips
        Set outPropAcc = outRecip.PropertyAccessor

        strDomain = outPropAcc.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
        strDomain = Split(strDomain, "@")(1)

        lngPreDom = InStr(strDomain, "@")
        lngPostDom = InStr(strDomain, ".")

        strDomain = LCase(Mid(strDomain, lngPreDom + 1, lngPostDom - lngPreDom - 1))

        Exit For
    Next

'   set subject value

    strSubject = LCase(Item.Subject)

'   set attachment name

    Set objAttachments = Item.Attachments
    strAttachment = LCase(objAttachments.Item(1).FileName)

'   if external recipient, check email contents

    If strDomain <> "exampleemail" _
        Then

        If InStr(strSubject, strDomain) = 0 _
            Or InStr(strAttachment, strDomain) = 0 _
            Or InStr(strAttachment, strSubject) = 0 _
            Then

            Response = "Attachment/Subject do not match Recipient(s)" & vbNewLine & "Send Anyway?"

            If MsgBox(Response, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Recipients") = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If anyone can help a girl in need I would be very grateful! Been trying to figure this out most of the day!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Attachment.PropertyAccessor object to read the PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN property (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B); if it's true it's an embedded image (usually in signatures).